# remove duplicates using distinct function based on two column values

Tags: r, distinct

I am trying to deduplicate a data set based on distinct values that appear in two columns, an example data set

My question is for second result, df.2col, when distinct is applied to remove duplicate rows on the Lang and Usage columns, the data frame resulting excludes the GO language row, which appears twice in df, but takes two different Usage values in df. I want the data frame to include both GO rows from the original data frame. Can you advise how to use the distinct function to keep all unique rows, based on two column values?

```
library(dplyr) 

df <- data.frame (lang =c ('Java','C','Python','GO','RUST','Javascript', 
                           'Cpp','Java','Julia','Typescript','Python','GO'), 
                  
                  value = c (21,21,3,5,180,9,12,21,6,0,3,6), 
                  
                  usage =c(21,21,0,99,44,48,53,21,6,8,0,6)) 


df.1col <- distinct(df, lang, .keep_all= TRUE)

df.2col <- distinct(df, value, usage, .keep_all= TRUE)
```

Comment: Your description says you want duplicates based on "Lang and Usage" but your code uses "value and usage".  Both GO and Julia have 6 for values and usage so only one row is preserved. You probably meant `distinct(df, lang, usage, .keep_all= TRUE) ` so this seems like a typo

Comment: you're not removing dupped rows based on the `lang` and `usage` columns in the `df.2col` code - you're removing rows based on the `value` and `usage` columns. is this what you're attempting to do: `df.2col <- df[!duplicated(df[,c("lang","usage")]),]` that retains both `GO` rows.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve the deduplication you're aiming for, where you want to keep unique rows based on two column values (`lang` and `usage` in your case), you should specify both of these columns in the `distinct` function. Currently, in your `df.2col` definition, you're using `value` and `usage` for deduplication, which is why the 'GO' language row is getting excluded.

Here's how you can modify the `df.2col` to include both 'GO' rows from the original dataframe by using `lang` and `usage` columns:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(lang = c('Java', 'C', 'Python', 'GO', 'RUST', 'Javascript', 
                          'Cpp', 'Java', 'Julia', 'Typescript', 'Python', 'GO'), 
                 value = c(21, 21, 3, 5, 180, 9, 12, 21, 6, 0, 3, 6), 
                 usage = c(21, 21, 0, 99, 44, 48, 53, 21, 6, 8, 0, 6)) 

df.1col <- distinct(df, lang, .keep_all = TRUE)

# Modified line
df.2col <- distinct(df, lang, usage, .keep_all = TRUE) 

print(df.2col)
```

In this code, `df.2col` will contain distinct rows based on the combination of `lang` and `usage` values. This means both 'GO' rows will be included if they have different usage values, which is what you're looking for.